# Distribution of $k$-matchings in a random graph

Tags: probability, graph-theory, random-graphs, matching-theory, distribution-tails

Take the Erdos-Renyi random graph $G(n,p)$, i.e. the random graph with $n$ vertices and where each possible edge has an independent probability of $p$ of being present. Recall that a $k$-matching is a disjoint union of $k$ edges. Let $X$ be a random variable equal to the number of subgraphs in $G(n,p)$ which are isomorphic to the $k$-matchings. I want to investigate the distribution of $X$.

Clearly for any fixed set of $2k$ vertices $(x_1, y_1, x_2, y_2, ..., x_k,y_k)$ from $G(n,p)$ the probability that there is an edge from ever $x_i$ to every $y_i$ is $p^{k}$. Therefore $\mathbb{E}(X) = 2k!\binom{n}{2k}p^{k}$. But what is the (approximate) distribution of $X$.

For concreteness I am interested in situations where say $p= \frac{1}{3}$ and I'd like to bound the tail probabilities `Chernoff style', i.e. I'd like to be able to bound from above $\mathbb{P}(X \le \frac{1}{a} \mathbb{E}(X)\,) $. Again for concretness say set $a=5$.

I'm sure this must be a studied problem but I'm not familiar with the literature in this area so any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you certain about your expected value computation? For even $n$, $K_n$ contains $(n-1)!!$ perfect matching, where $!!$ denotes the double-factorial. I would expect $\mathbb{E}(X) = (2k-1)!!\binom{n}{2k}p^{k}$.

Comment: Given that your subgraph is fixed and balanced, the asymptotic distribution is well-known. Have a look at the book Janson, Luczak, and Rucinski, section 3, https://faculty.sdu.edu.cn/_tsf/00/21/YvaIryj6ZvQf.pdf, or the more recent one by Frieze and Karonski, section 5. https://www.math.cmu.edu/~af1p/BOOK.pdf,

Comment: @ThomasLesgourgues Thank you for the links in fact for a general subgraph $H$ with $v$ vertices, $e$, and $a$ automorphisms the expected number of copies is $\binom{n}{v} \frac{v!}{a} \cdot p^e$ (this is in the link you gave. So in this case we get $\binom{n}{2k} \frac{2k!}{2^k k!}p^k$.) I believe a $k$-matching should have $2^k \cdot k!$ automorphisms, which matches the bound you suggest. Initially I was confused because I didn't understand the double factorial notation. In general since this factor only depends on $k$ it is not so important to me.

Comment: @ThomasLesgourgues so from Theorem 5.6. in the Frieze and Karonski book we know (since we are thinking of situations where $p$ is constant), that $X$ converges in distribution to a normal distribution, $N(\mathbb{E}(X), Var(X))$. We already worked out the expectation so all that remains is to work out the variance. Thanks for the help, sorry I can't upvote you because I don't have the right privilege.